# restful webservice public constructor not found

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am trying to invoke restful webservice using a client web application(simple client request from JSF MB). I need to create an interface for the webservice and then invoke the method in it. But if i use @Path at interface, its giving an error - public constructor not found during Jboss deployment. But If i give give @Path at implementation class. It is invoking the service fine and is working properly. I need to have a Java interface between Rest client and Restful webservice impl classes. Can anyone help? can we have Rest interface or something?

Client side:

```
ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/...../"); 
ClientResponse<String> response = request.get(String.class);
```

RestInterface:

```
package com.nee.interfaces; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 

@Path("/OrderManagementService") 
public interface OrderManagementServiceInterface { 
    @GET
    @Path("/GetListOfOrders") 
    void getListOfOrders(); 
}
```

IMPL:

```
package com.nee.implementations;
import com.nee.interfaces.OrderManagementServiceInterface;


public class OrderManagementServiceImpl implements OrderManagementServiceInterface {
    public void getListOfOrders() {
        System.out.println("am here");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.nee.interfaces.OrderManagementServiceInterface
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this has to match with resteasy-servlet url-pattern -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- to return data according to extension -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.media.type.mappings</param-name>
    <param-value>json : application/json, xml : application/xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Logs:

```
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/web]]
(MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a public constructor for class com.seagate.interfaces.OrderManagementServiceInterface
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.registered(POJOResourceFactory.java:35) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:120) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:106) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:83) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:72) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:383) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:225) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.3.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)[rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
```

Comment: Post your code. If you are using an interface then all the JAX-RS annotations should be defined on it.

Comment: pls update your post with well-formatted code.

Comment: Your interface code is not compilable. We also need your implementation code.

Comment: If i give @Path annotation at Impl class ..and configure the path at web.xml... rest everything same.. it works fine..

Comment: i dnt see any compilation errors at interface code.. please let me know if there are any... and as i said right now nothing big in impl class... i m concerned only about invoking interface... in IMPL i am just printing a message in console.. i have updates impl code too..

Comment: Am i missing any JAX-RS annotation which should be specific to java interface?

Comment: What version of JBoss are you deploying too?

Comment: The jboss version used is - jboss-eap-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simple answer to the above problem. In web.xml, instead of interface, i just had to configure  IMPL class instead of interface and continue setting @Path at interface

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.seagate.implementations.OrderManagementServiceImpl
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

AND IT WORKED :)...

Comment: that is what i've said to you in my answer! first part

Answer (score 1):

I guess your mistake is that you give an **interface** to RestEasy and the framework is trying to create an instance of it via reflection. Something like that will never work. Instead of the interface you should only specify implementation classes as a value for the parameter `resteasy.resources`. If you want to to be more dynamically try a combination of OSGi and REST. I didn't tried the example in [this](http://sarbarian.wordpress.com/2010/03/07/resteasy-and-osgi-perfect-match/) blog for myself, but you can have a look on that.

**UPDATE**

As you want to use your service from third party classes as well, why not wrap another interface with your REST webservice and that wrapped interface could be used in your third party classes. The webservice is then only use to delegate requests to a specific implementation of this interface. You can inject the implementation via a Dependency Injection framework like Spring, Google Juice or something else. Here is what I mean:

Your interface as an abstraction for your implementations:

```
interface IExecutionService {
   void executeStuff();
}
```

Then your REST Service:

```
@Path("/OrderManagementService")
class ExectionServiceDelegator {

   private IExecutionService wrappedServiceInterface;

   /**
    * play around with some DI frameworks for injecting your implementation
    */
   public void setIExecutionService(IExecutionService service) {
      wrappedServiceInterface = service;    
   }

   @GET
   @Path("/GetListOfOrders") 
   public void doingSomething() {
      service.executeStuff();
   }
}
```

You can use the interface `IExecutionService` in combination with a specific DI framework in your third party interfaces as well. Hope it's clear what I'm trying to do with the code above?!

Comment: Thanks christian...So we cant use interface for resteasy without OSGI???.. that is really sad. Usually for SOAP based webservices we used to have an interface to invoke the services.

Comment: even in OSGi you dont usually use direct interfaces for your abstraction of your REST services. It doesn't make so much sense in my opinion. Why? Because you actually don't work with specific implementation when calling a resource from the client. You just calling a URL and no classes. Only your application server is responsible for mapping these URL to resources (in your example the REST resource paths you specify in your classes). That means the URLs are your "interfaces" in some kind of fashion. You can easily change the an implementation by only defining the same paths for your classes...

Comment: ... Just change `the resteasy.resources` parameter to map the URL paths to your new class. Hope it is more clear now, that you don't have to depend to deeply on Java interfaces :) As you can see, the example in the provided blog don't use an interface as well. ;)

Comment: Actually my webservice will be used by some third party interface too.. I just dnt want to expose my implementation to them. That's y i am keen to have interface in between. And Yes Chris!!! I am able to invoke service if i set the path for impl class directly...I just wish  Java Reflection had not played such a spoil sport to invoke the interface directly.. Am still sad :(

Comment: why not using your REST as a bridge/adapter for an underlying implementation. i will update my answer to clarify what i mean.